# Why isn't my player falling (gravity) in Eclipse and LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, gravity

I am trying to make my player fall/go down, but he is not. He is just stuck on the map. He can't move. Can you please help?

Here is the code for the Screen. This is where I have all the methods like show, render, resize, pause, resume, hide, etc

```
package net.hasanbilal.prisonrevelations.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import net.hasanbilal.prisonrevelations.entities.Player;

public class Play implements Screen {

    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer otmr;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private Player porter;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/level1.tmx");

        otmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        porter = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/porter.png")));

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        otmr.setView(camera);
        otmr.render();

        otmr.getBatch().begin();
        porter.draw(otmr.getBatch());
        otmr.getBatch().end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.update();

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        otmr.dispose();

    }

}
```

Here is the code for the player

```
package net.hasanbilal.prisonrevelations.entities;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Player extends Sprite {

    /** 
     * x and y velocity
     */
    private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();

    //change 120 to 60*2 if it doesn't work
    private float speed = 60 * 2, gravity = 60 * 1.8f;

    public Player(Sprite s) {
        super(s);

    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch sb) {
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        super.draw(sb);

    }
    private void update(float deltaTime) {
        velocity.y -= gravity * deltaTime; //gravity to player

        if(velocity.y>speed)
            velocity.y = speed;
        else if(velocity.y < speed)
            velocity.y = -speed;

        setX(getX() + velocity.x * deltaTime);
        setY(getY() + velocity.y * deltaTime);

    }

}
```

This assignment is due soon! Please help!

Comment: The last if: "else if (velocity.y < speed)" shouldn't be "< -speed" (a minus before speed)?

Comment: Well that's the video did. I'm gonna try it without the minus when I get home

Comment: nope, removing minus didnt work

Comment: You need to add the minus not remove it. It becomes `if (velocity < -speed) velocity.y = -speed`. You could also remove the if block and replace it with `velocity.y = Math.max(-speed, Math.min(velocity.y, speed))`.

Comment: sorry, i already fixed it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I fixed it. All I had to do is add `porter.update(1);`between `porter.draw(otmr.getBatch());` and `otmr.getBatch().end();`

Comment: I think you complicated a little. LibGDX is there to help you, if in your PlayScreen you create a World ```world = new World(new Vector2 (gravity force in x, gravity force in y), true);``` and your player with b2body created ```player = new Entity(world, this);``` you will bring the gravity to the player inside the world. I use this Tutorial as my guide for B2Box

Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZm85UZQLd2SXQzsF-a0-pPF6IWDDdrXt "Youtube Tutorial") Youtube Tutorial.

Click [here](https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario "GitHub code") GitHub codes.